# Installing Oracle 12c on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6

Tags: oracle, installation, oracle-12c, errors, redhat

When I try to `./runInstaller` I get this error message:

> Source location is incomplete. Make sure you have downloaded and extracted all the relevant archives.

I have two database unzip folders, `database` and `database(0)`.

I copied `database(0)/install/.oui` to `database/install`, but the error message does not disappear.

This is the part of `runInstaller`:

```sh
# Abort the install, if install/.oui file is not found in the stage area
#
if [ ! -f $CMDDIR/install/.oui ]
then
        echo "Source location is incomplete. Make sure you have downloaded and extracted
all the relevant archives."
        exit 1
fi

#
```

This is the list of my database directory:

[image]

Certainly I have the `.oui` in `database/install`.

What can I do to resolve this error?

Comment: How have you unzipped theses files? If you run unzip command on terminal these files are extracted under a single directory called `database`. Delete these extracted files and try again with `[oracle@localhost]$ unzip linuxamd64_12102_database_1of2.zip` and redo same for second file. [Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135501/missing-files-installing-oracle-db-12c-on-oracle-linux-7-2/135506#135506) is a similar post and have useful comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Extracting the Installation Files](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LADBI/inst_task.htm#CIHJDAII)

> Oracle RDBMS software is available as two archive files. Ensure that
>   you extract both the archive files to the **same directory**.

Not just `install/.oui`, everything.